# Reference.cs file is not created when I add WSDL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, wsdl

I had been given with WSDL .When I added it as a web reference to my project Reference.cs file is not created.I need to have this proxy file for referring to to the web service i added.Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have an error in WSDL and the proxy can not be generated. Check for errors on your WSDL using this tool http://xmethods.net/ve2/Tools.po

Answer (score 0):

clear a project with version 4.0 and above a try sometime if you check for updates at least I've had the same problem.